# usage of that in "the bridge that artificial life"

Tags: that

"That chasm was life itself, the bridge that artificial life in which Aleksey Aleksandrovich had lived."

This quote is from Anna Karenina written by Leo Tolstoy.

I want to know how "that" is grammatically used in this sentence.

Thanks.

Comment: It's poetic.  Read it as "... the bridge *was* that artificial life..."

Comment: To expand further: *"That chasm was life itself, the bridge **[that stretched across the chasm was]** that artificial life in which Aleksey Aleksandrovich had lived."

Comment: @Greybeard Thanks! That helped my understanding a lot.